# Do I need to specify every selector to style a nested element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles

What is the proper way style a specific element that is deeply nested.

For example:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="main">
         <div class="profile">
            <div class="description">
                  <div class="name">John Doe</div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I want to make the name "John Doe" bold, do I name every selector:

```
.wrapper .content .main .profile .description .name { font-weight:bold; }
```

or do I just specify the selector directly like this:

```
.name { font-weight:bold; }
```

I am confused on what is the proper coding method. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you do **not** need to reference every parent element to target a nested element; you can simply target the element itself (such as with `.name`):

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="profile">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="name">John Doe</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, note that you can simply target any of the **ancestor** elements directly as well, where the rule will cascade down (targetting `.profile` will target `.profile` **as well as** everything nested within `.profile`, but **not** any of the ancestors or siblings of `.profile`):

```css
.profile {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">Main (not bold)
      <div class="profile">Profile
        <div class="description">
          <div class="name">John Doe</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you specify additional parent elements such as with `.wrapper .content .main .profile .description .name`, you're increasing what's known as the [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

This can play an important part when you have two rules that both target the same element, where the **most specific** rule will be applied (in the following, `.name` is a valid selector, but `.description .name` targets the **same element** and is **more specific**, so `.description .name` overrides `.name`):

```css
/* This gets applied */
.name {
  color: red;
}

/* This gets applied and takes priority, as it is more specific */
.description .name {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="profile">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="name">John Doe</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

And this increased specificity also be used to denote when you have two elements with the same class or selector, where you only want the rule to apply to a **particular element** (the second `.name` here doesn't have the parent `.description`, so although `.name` would be a valid selector for it, `.description .name` is **not**):

```css
.description .name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="profile">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="name">Name One -- targetted</div>
        </div>
        <div class="name">Name Two - not targetted</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the only hierarchy you want to be selected is the one in your example. If the hierarchy does not matter, use only one class name (`.name`). If you want to limit your selection to a specific hierarchy (how specific depends on your situation), go for more. It's not entirely uncommon for selectors to consist of many class names, each of them going even deeper into the hierarchy.

However, looking at your code, I want to suggest giving some of your tags IDs instead of class names. IDs are like class names, but they are unique across the whole document (there can/should be only one element with the same ID per document). In your example, is there more than one `.wrapper`, `.content`, and `.main`? Probably not. You'll judge for yourself, but those kinds of structures are typically unique and exist only once in a document.

If you give them IDs, they are `#wrapper`, `#content`, and `#main` respectively.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
     <div id="main">
         <div class="profile">
            <div class="description">
                  <div class="name">John Doe</div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you choose to do so, you can then get rid of the first three class names in your selector.

```
.profile .description .name
```

would be the same as:

```
#wrapper #content #main .profile .description .name
```

Except if there were elements in the document that had the same class names, but were outside of your `#wrapper`, `#content`, and `#main`.

The decision is yours, but it is commonplace to give such global structures (like `main`) IDs instead of class names, because they tend to be unique.